# Click Event for dynamic generated tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tabs, onclick

I'm using jQuery and a repeater to dynamically generate tab links.

Code example:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="App_Themes/Tabs.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.3-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="tabs">
            <asp:Repeater ID="TablLinkRepeater" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a href="#Tab<%# Eval("TabID") %>">
                        <%# Eval("TabName") %></a></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

            <%-- Tabs and Content --%>
            <asp:Repeater ID="TabRepeater" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="Tab<%# Eval("TabID") %>">
                        <h1>Tab #
                            <%# Eval("TabName") %>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="Content" id="ContentDiv" runat="server">
                            <%-- Some content--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="Index" runat="server" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" BorderStyle="none"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I now want to implement an onclick event to insert specific data of the clicked tab to the textbox. For example:

> First tab clicked  -> textbox1.text = "First tab was clicked";

> Second tab clicked -> textbox1.text = "Second tab was clicked";

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Tab1" data-text="First tab">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Tab2" data-text="Second tab">Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input id="result" type="text"/>


$(function(){
    $('#tabs').on("click","ul li a", function(){
    var link = $(this);
    $("#result").val(link.attr("data-text"));
  })
});
```

The key is jQuerys Delegated event handler and event bubbling on dynamically created tabs.